# ticklable in scientific notation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here I am using the IMDB Kaggle data set and I am plotting adjusted budget vs adjusted revenue and I am using popularity as the third variable for the bubble. There are values like 0 and 214 in the columns of budget_adj and revenue_adj, so I have taken the subset here. Now I am trying to have scientific notation along the axes since the variables are in millions and billions. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
%matplotlib inline
# Lot of preprocessing was done before the following
# step
df = movies.loc[(movies['budget_adj'] > 1e7) & (movies['revenue_adj'] > 1e7)]
x = df['budget_adj']
y = df['revenue_adj']
s = df['popularity']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 10)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
g = plt.scatter(x, y, s*3, alpha=0.5, c = 'blue')
g.axes.set_title('Title', fontsize = 20)
g.axes.set_xlabel('Adjusted Budget', fontsize=20)
g.axes.set_ylabel('Revenue Adjusted', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot[image]

So why the command `plt.ticklabel_format` is not working. I see `1e9` and `1e8` along the axes but that is not the scientific notation.

Comment: It is working. `1e9` means `1 * 10^9`, what else are you expecting?

Comment: @oarfish, I was expecting `x 10^9` and not `1e9`